# How to create a Script Mapper in Keycloak?

Tags: java, keycloak

I need to create a Protocol Mapper of type Script Mapper in Keycloak. The script should get a user attribute, check its size, and put it on the token. I found no documentation or examples of how a script should be created. From the bits and pieces I could gather, I guess I the script would need to look something like:

```
var value = user.getAttribute("myAttribute");
if (value.length > LIMIT) {
    value = value.substring(0,LIMIT);
}
token.setOtherClaims("myAttribute",value);
```

- Is this right? I made up user.getAttribute("myAttribute"). Is there a source of documentation where I can find how to get a Keycloak user attribute?
- does the script need to return anything?
  Any help would be mostly welcome.

Answer (score 40):

The magic of Script Mappers can be understood by looking at the keycloak sources here: [Source](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/2a4cee60440be6767e0f1e9155cebfa381cfb776/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/mappers/ScriptBasedOIDCProtocolMapper.java#L143)

The script can return something by using the exports variable like this

```
exports = "Claim Value"
```

The different types:

- user: [Source](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/UserModel.java) [JavaDoc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/UserModel.html)
- realm: [Source](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/RealmModel.java) [JavaDoc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/RealmModel.html)
- token: [Source](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/representations/IDToken.java) [JavaDoc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/representations/IDToken.html)
- userSession: [Source](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/UserSessionModel.java) [JavaDoc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/UserSessionModel.html)
- keycloakSession: [Source](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/KeycloakSession.java) [JavaDoc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/KeycloakSession.html)

Here is an example script:

```
// you can set standard fields in token
token.setAcr("test value");

// you can set claims in the token
token.getOtherClaims().put("claimName", "claim value");

// multi-valued claim (thanks to @ErwinRooijakkers)
token.getOtherClaims().put('foo', Java.to(['bars'], "java.lang.String[]"))

// work with variables and return multivalued token value
var ArrayList = Java.type("java.util.ArrayList");
var roles = new ArrayList();
var client = keycloakSession.getContext().getClient();
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
forEach.call(user.getClientRoleMappings(client).toArray(), function(roleModel) {
  roles.add(roleModel.getName());
});

exports = roles;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 11):

I needed this feature but could not find this "script mapper" thing in my freshly installed 10.0.2. Turns out it is not enabled by default, as seen in the docs here : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#profiles

To enable it, you can either :

- Create a file `standalone/configuration/profile.properties` with `feature.scripts=enabled`

or

- start the server with `bin/standalone.sh|bat -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled`

And it seems from [the source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/mappers/ScriptBasedOIDCProtocolMapper.java)

```
public boolean isSupported() {
    return Profile.isFeatureEnabled(Profile.Feature.SCRIPTS) && Profile.isFeatureEnabled(Profile.Feature.UPLOAD_SCRIPTS);
}
```

that the `upload_scripts` should be enabled likewise

I hope it will help someone

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I figured it also then found your post :-). Doc says that we should not enable script upload in production but we should deploy scripts on the server : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#using-keycloak-administration-console-to-upload-scripts