# Map a role attribute to a jwt token in keycloak

Tags: jwt, keycloak

I'm trying to map a realm-role attribute to a jwt token in keycloak using a client mapper. The idea is to assign certain default attributes to roles and the users that belong to the roles should inherit the attributes as well.

For instance, I have a realm-role called `web-master` and set a role attribute called `role-name` to `'Web master'`. I would like to see in my jwt token something like this `{... role_name: 'Web master' ...}`.

I tried to use a token mapper and set the *User Attribute* field to `role-name` and the *Token Claim Name* to `role_name` but it did not worked.

I also tried with `roleMappings['web-master'].attributes['role-name']` as *User Attribute* since the name maps to the *UserModel* but also didn't work.

I'm running out of options, is it a *Script mapper* the only possibility or there is an easier one?

Comment: Refer this SO post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485720/2458858

Comment: Thanks @tryingToLearn I already checked that ones... Script mapper should work even if it is a bit cumbersome.. maybe somebody knows an easier way.

Comment: If you find an alternate solution, do post it as an answer as I could not find any other way to do it either.

Comment: In fact put any solution that you followed and which worked. Will be helpful for people who land on your post.

Comment: I still haven't implemented the solution. Now the project focus changed and I work on other things. Hopefully sometime in the near future I'll have the chance to work on that and then I'll publish my solution here.

Comment: @atavio Did you manage to figure out a solution here? I'm trying to figure something out too but coming up empty!

Comment: @HyperionX no, sorry. As mentioned before I'm not working on that anymore. Still it would be interesting to know if there is a solution for this or if it is not possible/easy to do because it is not the right approach with keycloak.

Comment: @HyperionX this is a solution using a script mapper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68352004/aggregate-attributes-of-roles-in-claims-using-keycloak-script-mapper. Just remove the `currentClaims[k] = v;` line and attributes from roles are added to the token (but not aggregated if there are two roles with same attribute).

Comment: For anybody interested in learning about mapping user properties & attributes to token claims I found this and the next videos in this playlist as a good starting point to understand how it is supposed to work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlKfKwpASKE&list=PLRTM7OTAxy3OcmFEZeIcRgyYBjFR9yNyT