# Passing parameters that end up in the JWT when requesting a service account token with Keycloak?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak

I would like to have a **service account** client in Keycloak where I can pass an arbitrary key/value when requesting an access token. This key/value pair should then end up as claim.

So when requesting a service account token with e.g.:

```
$ http --form --auth myclient:mysecret POST http://localhost:7070/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  grant_type=client_credentials 
  foo=bar
```

I would like to see the extra parameter "foo=bar" as claim in the JWT:

```
{
  "iss": "http://localhost:7070/auth/realms/test",
  ...
  "clientId": "myclient",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Problems I encountered so far:

- Custom request form parameters are ignored.
- Custom scopes are always responed to with "Invalid scope".
- I couldn't get Dynamic Scopes, an experimental extension, to work although it's shown as enabled and I added a client scope "foo:*"
- URL Query Parameters or the raw form is not available in the AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper class so I can't get them from there in an Java extension

I'm currently using Keycloak 16 but also tried with the latest 20.

It does work with the `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange` as Keycloak does not check the client scopes in that flow but the flow does not fit for my current case.

Any ideas what else I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to build your own custom claim mapper as presented in [here](https://medium.com/@pavithbuddhima/how-to-add-custom-claims-to-jwt-tokens-from-an-external-source-in-keycloak-52bd1ff596d3), which would read the custom claims from the application and add them to the token.

Alternatively, you can also use [script mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518298/how-to-create-a-script-mapper-in-keycloak) to read the claims from the query parameters and add them to the token. Finally, you can also have a look at UMA flow and use the feature of [pushing claims](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_pushing_claims). The request could look like the following:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=myclient" \
             -d "client_secret=mysecret" \
             -d "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" \
             -d "claim_token_format=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt" \
             -d "claim_token=ewogICAgImZvbyIgOiBbImJhciJdCn0="  \
             -d "audience= myclient" \
             "http://localhost:7070/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

In the token you would have the following claim:

```
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "claims": {
          "foo": [
            "bar"
          ]
        },
        "rsid": "...",
        "rsname": "..."
      }
```